# Disable development mode on remote computers

Tags: powershell

Calc.exe is missing on newer computers in my domain. This script fixes the issue and restores the Calculator Shortcut to the Start Menu:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
$result = "powershell calculator fix ran"
$result | Out-File \\$computerlist\c$\smsflags\calculatorfix.exe


$TargetPath =  "shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
$ShortcutFile = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Calculator.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Is there any way to run this script against a list of computers in my domain that are saved in a .csv or .txt file?

Comment: This is what PowerShell Remoting was designed to do. Start by looking at `Invoke-Command`. Do you already have a GPO that enables remoting and sets execution policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'computerlist.txt'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
    Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

    $result = "powershell calculator fix ran"
    $result | Out-File 'C:\smsflags\calculatorfix.exe'
    $TargetPath =  "shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
    $ShortcutFile = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Calculator.lnk"
    $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
    $Shortcut.Save() 
}
```